# Leaflet overlay order (points, lines, and polygons)

Tags: javascript, leaflet, overlay, layer, panes

I'm working with the [Leaflet.StyledLayerControl](https://github.com/davicustodio/Leaflet.StyledLayerControl) plugin and would like to set my layers so that polygons always get pushed to the back, lines above the polygons, and points above the lines.

I have searched for solutions here but most refer to tilelayers or map panes (which I think only work with another version of leaflet 1.0).

I want to be able to toggle lines on and off and have them always be below points (same with polygons below polylines).

I'm guessing I have to do something with `setZIndex` or `bringToFront()` but i'm not sure where to start.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easy solution is really to use **Leaflet 1.0**, which provides you with [`map.createPane("paneName")`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#map-createpane) functionality. So you create like "polygonsPane", "linesPane" and "pointsPane", that you specify to each of your vector / shape layers using their [`pane`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#path-pane) option.

Once set, you can add / remove them to / from map, and they will always be inserted in the specified pane, hence respecting the pane's order.

```js
// Create necessary panes in correct order (i.e. "bottom-most" first).
map.createPane("polygonsPane");
map.createPane("linesPane");
map.createPane("pointsPane");

L.polygon([/* coords */], { pane: "polygonsPane" }).addTo(map);
L.polyline([/* coords */], { pane: "linesPane" }).addTo(map);
L.circleMarker([/* coords */], { pane: "pointsPane" }).addTo(map);
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/3v7hd2vx/51/

With **Leaflet 0.7**, you know that all vector layers are part of the same SVG container, being appended when added to map, hence they appear on top of all previously added vectors. Then you have to use `bringToFront()` and/or `bringToBack()` to re-sort them to whatever order you need.

You might be interested in that post for that case: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/166252/geojson-layer-order-in-leaflet-0-7-5/167904#167904

Comment: Okay just accepted! Sorry, this was my first post so I didn't really know how to.